# Number of ways to form a list from $\{1,2,3...k\}$ such that sum of the numbers is $n$, and one of the numbers is at least $d$.

Tags: combinatorics

For example, $k = 3$, $n = 4$, and $d = 2$, So we have to form a list from$\{1,2,3\}$ such that sum of the numbers is $4$ and one of the numbers is at least $2$. Possible lists are $\{1,1,2\}$, $\{1,2,1\}$, $\{2,1,1\}$, $\{3,1\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,2\}$. $\{1,1,1,1\}$ is not possible since every number is greater than $d = 2$.

Comment: Can you answer the related (*easier*) question where you form a sequence of numbers such that the sum is $n$ but *all numbers are strictly less than* $d$?  How about the question where we don't care about whether any numbers are larger than $d$ or not?  Do you see how knowledge of these two answers gives you the answer to your original question?

Comment: For the second part, will finding the coefficient of x^n from generating function work?

Comment: If you are happy to use generating functions, yes, and that approach will work for the first part too.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure how to use it for the part with restrictions. This is what I had in mind, answer = sum of coefficients of $x^{n-d}$ , $x^{n-(d+1)}$ , .... , $x^{n-k}$. Not sure if it's right.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are okay with using generating functions for an answer:

If we don't care about the restriction that one of the numbers is at least $d$, then this is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^k)^i = \dfrac{1}{1-x-x^2-\dots-x^k}$$

If we want to count how many violated the condition that at least one number is at least $d$, that is akin to counting the number of solutions where all of the numbers are less than $d$ which is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (x+x^2+\dots+x^{d-1})^i = \dfrac{1}{1-x-x^2-\dots-x^{d-1}}$$

The answer is then the coefficient of $x^n$ in the difference of these:

$$\dfrac{1}{1-x-x^2-\dots-x^k}-\dfrac{1}{1-x-x^2-\dots-x^{d-1}}$$

Comment: inclusion-exclusion gotcha! thanks a lot

Comment: I wouldn't call this inclusion exclusion.  It is merely using the fact that $|A|+|A^c|=|\Omega|$